# node js fire a new GET request to fetch the data from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

HHi,

I'm working on a project for an online course and I need to make one change to the project.  I don't exactly understand what the code reviewer is saying I'm doing wrong.  His comment is:

> Here you need to fire a new GET request to fetch the data from server.
>
> The requests GET and POST have a specific purpose.
>
> GET request to fetch data from server/db
>
> POST is used to create new data in server/db
>
> These requests must do the task they are designed for, nothing else.

This is the problem area of my code:

```
let postData = async(url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
    let temp = data.main.temp;
    let zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
    let feelings = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
    let date = newDate;
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( { temp, zip, feelings, date }),
    });
    try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = newData.date;
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = newData.temp;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = newData.feelings;
        return newData
    }catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}
```

This is my full code:

app.js:

```
let apiURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=524901&APPID=' + apiKey + '&zip=';
const endURL = ',us';

// Create a new date instance dynamically with JS
let d = new Date();
let newDate = d.getMonth()+'.'+ d.getDate()+'.'+ d.getFullYear();

document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', performAction);

let content = document.getElementById('feelings').value;

function performAction(e){

let zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;

    let url = apiURL + zip + endURL;

apiCall(url)
.then(async function(data){
    console.log(data);
    let res = await postData('/', data);
    console.log(res);
});
};

const apiCall = async (url) =>{
    const res = await fetch(url);
    try {
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data)
        return data;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};

let postData = async(url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
    let temp = data.main.temp;
    let zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
    let feelings = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
    let date = newDate;
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( { temp, zip, feelings, date }),
    });
    try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = newData.date;
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = newData.temp;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = newData.feelings;
        return newData
    }catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}
```

server.js:

```
let projectData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes

const express = require('express');

// Start up an instance of app

const app = express();

/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

// Cors for cross origin allowance

// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('website'));

// Setup Server

const port = 8000;
const server = app.listen(port, listening);

function listening(){
    console.log(`running on localhost: ${port}`);
};

app.get('/weather', getData);

function getData(req, res){
    res.send(projectData)
    console.log(projectData)
};

app.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'website'})
    })
    .post(getWeather);

function getWeather(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    projectData = req.body;
    console.log(projectData);
    res.status(200).send(projectData);
};
```

I have no idea what the changes would look like because I wrote this code following the same structure that they taught in the lessons.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks alot,
Mike

Comment: Can you explain more about the purpose of your API ? Given the code you show us here it's not 100% clear what you are trying to do. Shouldn't be to much of a hazzle to get you into the right direction. I guess you are trying to design an API to let the user get and create weather data from and to `http://api.openweathermap.org/` , correct ?

Comment: Also I'm a bit confused how you're using `document` here - is `app.js` a clientside file ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to fetch data from API so he is trying to say that when you are trying to fetch data from api you need GET request.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to write this function:

```
const updateUI = async () =>{
    const res = await fetch('/weather');
    try {
        const allData = await res.json();
        console.log(allData)
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = allData.date;
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = allData.temp;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = allData.feelings;
        return allData
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};
```

and edit my postData function to this:

```
let postData = async(url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
    let temp = data.main.temp;
    let zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
    let feelings = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
    let date = newDate;
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( { temp, zip, feelings, date }),
    });
    try {
        updateUI()
/*        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = newData.date;
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = newData.temp;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = newData.feelings;
        return newData
*/    
    }catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }

}
```